# How to save the object size and dragging position on every reloading in using JS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make an object which has drag and resize. But I want this object dimension and position changes saved on the same where I left. Whenever I open the or reload the page I want the object position and resizing saved wherever I left last time. 
How can I do this?

**HTML Code is**

```
<div id="pane">
<div id="title">Resize, Drag or Snap Me!</div>
</div>
<div id="ghostpane"></div>
```

**CSS Code is**

```
body {
overflow: hidden;
}

#pane {
    position: absolute;
    width: 45%;
    height: 45%;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;


    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    border: 2px solid purple;
    background: #fefefe;
}

#title {
    font-family: monospace;
    background: purple;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#ghostpane {
    background: #999;
    opacity: 0.2;

    width: 45%;
    height: 45%;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;

    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 98;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

**JS Code is**

```
"use strict";

// Minimum resizable area
var minWidth = 60;
var minHeight = 40;

// Thresholds
var FULLSCREEN_MARGINS = -10;
var MARGINS = 4;

// End of what's configurable.
var clicked = null;
var onRightEdge, onBottomEdge, onLeftEdge, onTopEdge;

var rightScreenEdge, bottomScreenEdge;

var preSnapped;

var b, x, y;

var redraw = false;

var pane = document.getElementById('pane');
var ghostpane = document.getElementById('ghostpane');

function setBounds(element, x, y, w, h) {
    element.style.left = x + 'px';
    element.style.top = y + 'px';
    element.style.width = w + 'px';
    element.style.height = h + 'px';
}

function hintHide() {
  setBounds(ghostpane, b.left, b.top, b.width, b.height);
  ghostpane.style.opacity = 0;

  // var b = ghostpane.getBoundingClientRect();
  // ghostpane.style.top = b.top + b.height / 2;
  // ghostpane.style.left = b.left + b.width / 2;
  // ghostpane.style.width = 0;
  // ghostpane.style.height = 0;
}


// Mouse events
pane.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMove);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', onUp);

// Touch events 
pane.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchDown);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);
document.addEventListener('touchend', onTouchEnd);


function onTouchDown(e) {
  onDown(e.touches[0]);
  e.preventDefault();
}

function onTouchMove(e) {
  onMove(e.touches[0]);     
}

function onTouchEnd(e) {
  if (e.touches.length ==0) onUp(e.changedTouches[0]);
}

function onMouseDown(e) {
  onDown(e);
  e.preventDefault();
}

function onDown(e) {
  calc(e);

  var isResizing = onRightEdge || onBottomEdge || onTopEdge || onLeftEdge;

  clicked = {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    cx: e.clientX,
    cy: e.clientY,
    w: b.width,
    h: b.height,
    isResizing: isResizing,
    isMoving: !isResizing && canMove(),
    onTopEdge: onTopEdge,
    onLeftEdge: onLeftEdge,
    onRightEdge: onRightEdge,
    onBottomEdge: onBottomEdge
  };
}

function canMove() {
  return x > 0 && x < b.width && y > 0 && y < b.height
  && y < 30;
}

function calc(e) {
  b = pane.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.clientX - b.left;
  y = e.clientY - b.top;

  onTopEdge = y < MARGINS;
  onLeftEdge = x < MARGINS;
  onRightEdge = x >= b.width - MARGINS;
  onBottomEdge = y >= b.height - MARGINS;

  rightScreenEdge = window.innerWidth - MARGINS;
  bottomScreenEdge = window.innerHeight - MARGINS;
}

var e;

function onMove(ee) {
  calc(ee);

  e = ee;

  redraw = true;

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  if (!redraw) return;

  redraw = false;

  if (clicked && clicked.isResizing) {

    if (clicked.onRightEdge) pane.style.width = Math.max(x, minWidth) + 'px';
    if (clicked.onBottomEdge) pane.style.height = Math.max(y, minHeight) + 'px';

    if (clicked.onLeftEdge) {
      var currentWidth = Math.max(clicked.cx - e.clientX  + clicked.w, minWidth);
      if (currentWidth > minWidth) {
        pane.style.width = currentWidth + 'px';
        pane.style.left = e.clientX + 'px'; 
      }
    }

    if (clicked.onTopEdge) {
      var currentHeight = Math.max(clicked.cy - e.clientY  + clicked.h, minHeight);
      if (currentHeight > minHeight) {
        pane.style.height = currentHeight + 'px';
        pane.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';  
      }
    }

    hintHide();

    return;
  }

  if (clicked && clicked.isMoving) {

    if (b.top < FULLSCREEN_MARGINS || b.left < FULLSCREEN_MARGINS || b.right > window.innerWidth - FULLSCREEN_MARGINS || b.bottom > window.innerHeight - FULLSCREEN_MARGINS) {
      // hintFull();
      setBounds(ghostpane, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      ghostpane.style.opacity = 0.2;
    } else if (b.top < MARGINS) {
      // hintTop();
      setBounds(ghostpane, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight / 2);
      ghostpane.style.opacity = 0.2;
    } else if (b.left < MARGINS) {
      // hintLeft();
      setBounds(ghostpane, 0, 0, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight);
      ghostpane.style.opacity = 0.2;
    } else if (b.right > rightScreenEdge) {
      // hintRight();
      setBounds(ghostpane, window.innerWidth / 2, 0, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight);
      ghostpane.style.opacity = 0.2;
    } else if (b.bottom > bottomScreenEdge) {
      // hintBottom();
      setBounds(ghostpane, 0, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerWidth, window.innerWidth / 2);
      ghostpane.style.opacity = 0.2;
    } else {
      hintHide();
    }

    if (preSnapped) {
      setBounds(pane,
        e.clientX - preSnapped.width / 2,
        e.clientY - Math.min(clicked.y, preSnapped.height),
        preSnapped.width,
        preSnapped.height
      );
      return;
    }

    // moving
    pane.style.top = (e.clientY - clicked.y) + 'px';
    pane.style.left = (e.clientX - clicked.x) + 'px';

    return;
  }

  // This code executes when the mouse moves without clicking

  // style cursor
  if (onRightEdge && onBottomEdge || onLeftEdge && onTopEdge) {
    pane.style.cursor = 'nwse-resize';
  } else if (onRightEdge && onTopEdge || onBottomEdge && onLeftEdge) {
    pane.style.cursor = 'nesw-resize';
  } else if (onRightEdge || onLeftEdge) {
    pane.style.cursor = 'ew-resize';
  } else if (onBottomEdge || onTopEdge) {
    pane.style.cursor = 'ns-resize';
  } else if (canMove()) {
    pane.style.cursor = 'move';
  } else {
    pane.style.cursor = 'default';
  }
}

animate();

function onUp(e) {
  calc(e);

  if (clicked && clicked.isMoving) {
    // Snap
    var snapped = {
      width: b.width,
      height: b.height
    };

    if (b.top < FULLSCREEN_MARGINS || b.left < FULLSCREEN_MARGINS || b.right > window.innerWidth - FULLSCREEN_MARGINS || b.bottom > window.innerHeight - FULLSCREEN_MARGINS) {
      // hintFull();
      setBounds(pane, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      preSnapped = snapped;
    } else if (b.top < MARGINS) {
      // hintTop();
      setBounds(pane, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight / 2);
      preSnapped = snapped;
    } else if (b.left < MARGINS) {
      // hintLeft();
      setBounds(pane, 0, 0, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight);
      preSnapped = snapped;
    } else if (b.right > rightScreenEdge) {
      // hintRight();
      setBounds(pane, window.innerWidth / 2, 0, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight);
      preSnapped = snapped;
    } else if (b.bottom > bottomScreenEdge) {
      // hintBottom();
      setBounds(pane, 0, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerWidth, window.innerWidth / 2);
      preSnapped = snapped;
    } else {
      preSnapped = null;
    }

    hintHide();

  }

  clicked = null;

}
```

[Demo Testing link](https://codepen.io/zz85/pen/gbOoVP)

Comment: you can save position in sessionStorage and read it on load - if exists apply the coords otherwise do nothing (it means you havent done any transformation or loading page for the first time)

Comment: can you please brief little how can able to save these value in sessionstorage and localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

Use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: May You please brief me how could i save these value to sessionStorage or LocalStorage?